# How can I improve the binding update preformance of a listbox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, data-binding

So here is the scenario, I've got an operation that clears an ObservableCollection, runs a query, and repopulates the collection with the query results.  This collection is databound to by a listbox.  Here's the kicker, 500 query results causes some serious update time which blocks the user interface for what is perceived as "too long" (in reality it's .5-2 seconds on most systems) Either way, I know that the query is fast enough, as is adding the elements, so I have narrowed it down to the presentation layer.

Doing some testing, I get notably better performance if I remove the item template from the listbox (duh) but not so much better that it would even meet the expectations that were communicated to me.  I updated bindings to be one way where applicable, I changed the virtualization mode to recycle, and I made sure I was using static resources, none of the above made a noticeable impact on the re-draw.  I was wondering if anyone else had a good idea how to improve the performance of a listbox being populated with large quantities of items?

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" ItemsSource="{Binding SerialResults}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UnitHistoryTemplate}" BorderThickness="2" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">

<DataTemplate x:Key="UnitHistoryTemplate">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="UnitFailureItemTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Margin="4,0,4,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Grid d:DesignWidth="580" d:DesignHeight="30" Background="#00000000">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="load"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="run"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ser"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="mot"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="result"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Load" Text="{Binding Load.LoadNumber, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="4,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Run" Text="{Binding Run.RunNumber, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="4,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Serial" Text="{Binding Unit.SerialNumber, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="4,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Mot" Text="{Binding Unit.MotString, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="4,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Grid.Column="3"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Result" Text="{Binding Run.Result, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="4,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, GridBox"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Unit.Failed, Mode=OneTime}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UnitFailureItemTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" Grid.Column="5">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Run.Result, Mode=OneTime}" Value="Aborted">
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter TargetName="Result" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And since it has been asked about a few times below, no it's not my observable collection... I'm suppressing the event by doing a batch of updates and reassigning the items source to a new instance.

```
    public async void FindUnitHistory()
    {
        if (IsCaching)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (_serialSearch.Length <= MIN_SEARCH_LENGTH)
        {
            SerialResults.Clear();
            return;
        }


        var newData = new ObservableCollection<UnitHistory>();

        await TaskEx.Run(() =>
            {
                var results = from load in cache.LoadData.AsParallel()
                              from run in load.Runs
                              from unit in run.Units
                              where unit.SerialNumber.StartsWith(_serialSearch)
                              orderby run.RunNumber ascending
                              orderby load.LoadNumber descending
                              select new UnitHistory(load, run, unit);
                foreach (var p in results)
                {
                    newData.Add(p);
                }
            });


        SerialResults = newData;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the results (of your query) which happens to be a large number of data, then I would suggest you to use DataPager with DataGrid/ListView/ListBox, and show only as many items as the available space can accommodate (without creating vertical scrollbar). For that, you've to write a DataPager control, as it doesn't come with WPF (though Silverlight has DataPager!). (I've written DataPager for my project to solve similar problem. It's fun to write your own controls!)

But even before that you can try this: (it *may* work)

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Instead of this:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

You may also want to have a look at these articles:

[Data virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344)
[UI Virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=338)
[How can I filter data virtualized items in WPF?](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=411)
[How can I sort data virtualized items in WPF?](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=426)

EDIT: Since when you populate your resultCollection, each Add() fires a collection changed event, which is handled by your WPF controls. So that is not a good idea, since if there are 1000 items to be added to your resultCollection, then there are 1000 events handled by your code (or WPF controls). That is unnecessary. So you can suppress this events as Marijn suggested.

But I would suggest you to do this trick to suppress the unnecessary events:

```
ObservableCollection<Result> temp = resultCollection;
resultCollection = null ; // make it null so it will not fire any event anymore to be handled by wpf!
temp.clear()

foreach(/*your code*/)
{
     temp.Add(item); //since temp is not bound to any control, temp's collection changed event will not be handled by anyone! Means, No Handler, No Code to Execute, No time waste!
}

resultCollection = temp ; //this fires event, which is handled by your code/ wpf.
```

Comment: the virtualizing stack panel there was on the data template, and I've also completely removed before, it made no discernable difference.

Comment: Also, that's how my code used to be *points at above observable collection code* it is the repopulation and rendering code that seems to be slow.

Comment: @Firoso.. it seems the unnecessary events which make your code slow, try suppressing them as I suggested above!

Comment: @Firoso.. can you post the relevant code from your presenter/viewmodel?

Comment: @Nawaz, what am I missing O_O  I just added the VM code, and in fact changed it to a list instead of an observable collection, there is NO discernable change because i'm building a new list and re-assigning it.

Comment: @Firoso... Btw, why do you need the ItemsControl? Each result has a collection called Unit.Failed? Unit.Failed is a collection? From it's name, it doesn't seem so. Try commenting the ItemsControl and see the performance!

Comment: it is, it's a list of failed elements... it's named that way to match up to a database field.

Comment: @Firoso.. alright. Now please try commenting the ItemsControl and see the performance! I'm curious to know why this code is slow. 500 items is not a big deal after all!

Comment: it is "better" but not drastically so, 20% tops.

Comment: @Firoso.. so your listbox is showing 500 items (with a vertical scrollbar), right? If yes, then you need to change the design. Showing 500 items in a listbox, is not a good idea, in my opinion. You may want DataPager!

Comment: but it should only be generating itemcontainers for 10 or so...  :-/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to override the OnCollectionChanged method to temporarily suppress CollectionChanged events when doing a bulk add to an observable collection. See for instance [this post](http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/bulk-loading-in-observablecollection/).

Comment: After reading the update to your question, I don't think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

*Please excuse me if this is wrong, I don't have any experience with the new async/Task stuff yet.*

Short answer: Don't set SerialResults to your new ObservableCollection until you've completed adding items to it.

Long answer: ObservableCollection has to raise its CollectionChanged event every single time you add an item to it. Since the ObservableCollection is bound to an ItemsControl, every time that event fires the ItemsControl needs to redraw the window, blocking anything else from happening.

See Marijn's post about creating your own ObservableCollection type for a workaround.

Comment: as posted above, I am not doing this O_O